#stripe-payments SubscriptionAddInvoiceItemOptions no metadata option
I have a solution that creates a stripe subscription plus a one time fee.  This all works in my  .NET C# API calls with Stripe, but I cannot figure out how to add MetaData to the invoice item which is the one time charge.  The Stripe object to create the one time charge is theSubscriptionAddInvoiceItemOptions, which doesn't have a MetaData property.
I've tried several examples, including reflection to set the MetaData for the invoice item but nothing has worked so far.
I can stash the MetaData at the Invoice level, but really was hoping to include it with the one time line item charge.
I really feel that this is a limitation of the API, but I'm not positive.
I've also been through examples of creating a draft subscription invoice but this also doesn't seem to work, so there is no way that the Stripe payment can later finalize the subscription.
Thanks,
Karl..

Try creating an Invoice Item first for the one-time charge, then create the Subscription (without using add_invoice_items for the one-time charge). The first invoice for the Subscription should include the Invoice Item.
